# Can't get value from dynamically created hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dynamic

I got an element, dynamically added on the page after an ajax call, that has an hidden input field within:

```
<div id='added_title'>
<b>Title</b> 
<input type='hidden' id='title_n' name='title_n' value='TITLE_NAME'/>
</div>
```

After the ajax call i need to get input field value to show it in another div but without any event or click, just after the ajax call finish.

i tried:

```
$("input[name='title_n']").val();
$("input[id='title_n']").val();
$("#title_n").val()
$("#added_title input[name='title_n']").val();
```

I also tried to use data-attribute like this:

```
<div id='added_title' data-title = 'TITLE_NAME'>
    <b>Title</b> 
    </div>
```

accessing the data with:

```
$('#added_title').data('title');
```

But i always get "undefined" value.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/tools/get_title.php',
    data:  { title: title},
        success: function (response) {
            $("#title_div").html(response);
        }
});
```

where "title_div" is the ID of "added_title" parent.

Comment: Show you ajax call code

Comment: And you are of course trying to get the value *after* the element has been inserted.

Comment: Of course I am. The Ajax call load content into a div, as the content is loaded I'm trying to get the value from the input field just loaded and show it in another element within the page.

Comment: did you put your js code in onload()?

Comment: That's not what your code above shows. Your code shows that the code for checking the `val()` of the hidden input is NOT dependent on that field existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#title_n").val()` is the fastest and easiest way to get the value that you are after.

The problem with the code you have above, is that the `$.ajax` call is fired, then code continues to execute, including, presumably the call to the hidden input.

Then the `$.ajax` call completes and fires the success event, which puts said element on the page.

You can't do anything with the hidden element until after the $.ajax call is finished, so you should have your code dealing with that element in a function that is called in the `success` function of the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: putting the value getter inside the ajax success function works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: No worries! Glad to help (have seen this mistake by lots of devs before).